# Pyspark inner join 3 tables

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, pyspark

My goal is joining 3 tables in Pyspark dataframes,

`TableA`, `TableB` and `TableC` all have an ID like a Key to merge.

I want to join three tables and create a new Pyspark dataframe.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply join them as below:

```
final_table = (tableA.join(tableB, on = [tableA.ID == tableB.ID], how = 'inner')
                     .join(tableC, on = [tableA.ID == tableB.ID], how = 'inner'))
```

Comment: You can also use `on='ID'` if you want.

Comment: From your code...how can I select specific columns from final Merge??  Example like SQL --> Select TableA.col1, TableA.col2, TableB.col1, TableB.col2, TableC.col3, TableC.col3 ??

Comment: final_table = (tableA.join(xxxxxxxxx).join(xxxxxxxxx).select('column1', 'column2', 'column3))