# Add suffix to column names of a table in an INNER JOIN of pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Pyspark, so apology if this is too basic of a question. I have looked at quite a few StackOverflow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62728542/1330974) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71038163/1330974), but cannot get the code to working.

I am trying to convert the following relatively simple SQL code to Pyspark.

```
SELECT
 gdp.*, 
 date_format(cset.target_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as target_date_ext,
 cset.45d_yield AS 45d_yield_ext,
 cset.90d_yield AS 90d_yield_ext,
-- more lines like above two where I am just appending '_ext' to the columns in 'cset' table
FROM hashed_customer_set cset
INNER JOIN gdp
ON gdp.customer_id = cset.hashed_customer_id 
AND gdp.region_id = cset.region_id 
AND gdp.marketplace_id = cset.marketplace_id
AND gdp.dataset_day = cset.snapshot_day
```

This is the Pyspark code that I have so far --

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Customers data is a small one like 50KB in size; 8000 rows
df_hashed_customer_panel = spark.read.parquet(f"s3://my-bucket/customers/")
df_gdp_v2_filtered = spark.read.parquet(f"s3://my-bucket/gdp/region_id={region_id}/marketplace_id={marketplace_id}/")

# Below is my attempt to add '_ext' to columns from hashed_customer_panel table
hashed_customer_panel_alias = 'hcp'
hashed_customer_panel_cols = [F.col(col_name).alias(''.join([hashed_customer_panel_alias, '.', col_name, '_ext'])) for col_name in df_hashed_customer_panel.columns]
print(hashed_customer_panel_cols)
# stdout from print statement above
# [Column<b'hashed_customer_id AS `hcp.hashed_customer_id_ext`'>, Column<b'region_id AS `hcp.region_id_ext`'>, Column<b'marketplace_id AS `hcp.marketplace_id_ext`'>, Column<b'snapshot_day AS `hcp.snapshot_day_ext`'>, Column<b'45d_yield AS `hcp.45d_yield_ext`'>, Column<b'90d_yield AS `hcp.90d_yield_ext`'>, Column<b'target_date AS `hcp.target_date_ext`'>]

# This gdp table has about two hundred columns, so I'll not show the print out of them
gdp_v2_filtered_alias = 'gdp2'
df_gdp_v2_filtered_cols = [F.col(col_name).alias(''.join([gdp_v2_filtered_alias, '.', col_name])) for col_name in df_gdp_v2_filtered.columns]

# Here, I'm combining columns from hashed_customer_panel (with '_ext' appended to each) and that from gdp table for final output columns. 
final_output_cols = hashed_customer_panel_cols + df_gdp_v2_filtered_cols
print(final_output_cols)

# Below is my attempt to INNER JOIN these two tables above
df_final = df_gdp_v2_filtered.alias(gdp_v2_filtered_alias).join(
    F.broadcast(df_hashed_customer_panel.alias(hashed_customer_panel_alias)),
    on=(
    (F.col(f"{gdp_v2_filtered_alias}.customer_id") == F.col(f"{hashed_customer_panel_alias}.hashed_customer_id")) & 
    (F.col(f"{gdp_v2_filtered_alias}.region_id") == F.col(f"{hashed_customer_panel_alias}.region_id")) &
    (F.col(f"{gdp_v2_filtered_alias}.marketplace_id") == F.col(f"{hashed_customer_panel_alias}.marketplace_id")) &
    (F.col(f"{gdp_v2_filtered_alias}.dataset_day") == F.col(f"{hashed_customer_panel_alias}.snapshot_day"))
    ),
    how='inner'
).select(*final_output_cols)

print(f"{log_prefix} => Row count of df_final: {df_final.count():,}")
```

It is returning the error message below...

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'region_id' is ambiguous, could be: gdp2.region_id, hcp.region_id.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.package$AttributeSeq.resolve(package.scala:259)
```

I believe I have taken care of that confusion by `f"{gdp_v2_filtered_alias}.region_id"` and `f"{hashed_customer_panel_alias}.region_id"`.

If someone experienced with Pyspark could review the above INNER JOIN code and to guide me what I can to do to 1) resolve this ambiguity and 2) if I am adding the suffixes the Pyspark-y way, I would sincerely appreciate the help. Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out eventually. The ambiguity was resolved by the change in the following lines of code:

```
# Note that I modified two things
# 1) changed 'F.col(col_name).alias(...)' to 'F.col(f"{hashed_customer_panel_alias}.{col_name}").alias(...), which resolved the ambiguity
# 2) '.alias(''.join([hashed_customer_panel_alias, '.', col_name, '_ext']))' becomes '.alias(''.join([col_name, '_ext']))', which prevented me from creating new columns in the form of 'hcp.*' or 'gdp2.*' (including aliases as part of the final column names)
hashed_customer_panel_alias = 'hcp'
hashed_customer_panel_cols = [F.col(f"{hashed_customer_panel_alias}.{col_name}").alias(''.join([col_name, '_ext'])) for col_name in df_hashed_customer_panel.columns]
print(hashed_customer_panel_cols)

gdp_v2_filtered_alias = 'gdp2'
df_gdp_v2_filtered_cols = [F.col(f"{gdp_v2_filtered_alias}.{col_name}").alias(''.join([col_name])) for col_name in df_gdp_v2_filtered.columns]
```

Then everything works as expected. I am leaving this comment as an unofficial answer in case someone in the future runs into similar ambiguity issue in Pyspark while trying to append suffixes/prefixes. I will wait for Pyspark experts to share how I could have done this in a cleaner (Pyspark-y) way, and if there's any, I'd accept that as the final answer. Thanks all!